# Different Script (SAP GUI) Codes for the same process in two different computers

Tags: macros, sap-gui

I want to automate some operations for my works so I record a Script on SAP GUI(SAP LOGON PAD 720), then use it to create a excel macro and it works perfectly on my computer, but when I try to run it in other computers, it doesn't work at all and when I record the same process in other PC's the Script's code is different than that one which appeared in my PC.  I want to know how this can be possible, how can I change the "code form" or "code language" on my PC so when I record a script it can be used on every computer.

This is the Script from my PC

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "vl03n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'This is the script I recorded from my computer,in other pc this "LIKP-VBELN" doesnt appear
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLIKP-VBELN").text = "8105148724"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press
```

And this is if I record the same process from others PC's

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "vl03n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'here is when the error begin "LIKP-VBELN" doesnt appear anymore so that is why the macro doesnt work
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt").text = "8105148724"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the LAN connection for the client and ensure its set to High Speed.

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Hi, how can I do that? Is it from SAP ? When I said "other computers" I must say that is any of my colleague's computers, who sit beside me.

Comment: Google: SAP LAN connection high speed     ;-)

Comment: I search about it in google, but couldn´t follow that steps in my pc, can´t find the same screen,Anyway, I develop another macro that runs perfect in other pc's. Thank you.